# Hybrid graphics on desktop with Ivy Bridge

Tags: intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, gpu

While there's plenty of resources on laptop hybrid graphics, I couldn't find any relevant info on desktop hybrid graphics. Suppose following scenario: I have an Ivy Bridge CPU with integrated GPU and a discrete GPU. Can I switch between them without rebooting? (My display has two inputs, so I want to literally switch active devices)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

bumblebee. http://bumblebee-project.org/

Switching devices can be done using xrandr. Try `xrandr -q`.

Comment: I think that only works with Nvidia GPUs and on laptops, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.